Mysql2 pool and ssh2 tunnel returning timeout error despite keepAlive enabled
My app lets users create and run custom reports using report filters (dropdown options are fetched through separate database connection and sql).
Since the filters can have different database sources, in order to get their options, I wanted to loop through each filter, create a pool if none exists using the connection string and ssh string (if required) or reuse the existing pool associated to the filter's db_id then perform the filter's sql query.
I use a Pool Manager class that consists of a map for pools that will hold one pool for each db_id the app ecounters and another map for ssh tunnels - also one tunnel for each db_id. The issue is despite enabling keepAlive in both creation of pool and ssh tunnel, the API still returns this error: Error: connect ETIMEDOUT.
pool_manager.js
const { Client } = require('ssh2');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

class PoolManager {
    constructor() {
        this.sshConnections = new Map();  // Store active SSH tunnels
        this.pools = new Map();           // Store MySQL connection pools
    }

    async createSSHTunnel(dbId, sshConfig) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let config;

            if (sshConfig.keyFile) {
                config = {
                    host: sshConfig.host,
                    port: sshConfig.port || 22,
                    username: sshConfig.user,
                    privateKey: fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, sshConfig.keyFile))
                };
            } else {
                config = {
                    host: sshConfig.host,
                    port: sshConfig.port || 22,
                    username: sshConfig.user,
                    password: sshConfig.password
                };
            }

            // Check if the tunnel already exists
            if (this.sshConnections.has(dbId)) {
                console.log("Reusing existing SSH tunnel for dbId:", dbId);
                const sshClient = this.sshConnections.get(dbId);
                if (sshClient.isConnected) {
                    return resolve(sshClient.stream);
                }
            }

            const sshClient = new Client();
            sshClient.isConnected = false;
            this.sshConnections.set(dbId, sshClient);

            const forwardConfig = {
                srcHost: sshConfig.localHost || '127.0.0.1',
                srcPort: sshConfig.localPort || 3307,
                dstHost: sshConfig.remoteHost,
                dstPort: sshConfig.remotePort || 3306
            };

            // Event listener to handle SSH tunnel readiness
            sshClient.on('ready', () => {
                console.log("SSH Tunnel ready for dbId:", dbId);
                sshClient.forwardOut(
                    forwardConfig.srcHost,
                    forwardConfig.srcPort,
                    forwardConfig.dstHost,
                    forwardConfig.dstPort,
                    (err, stream) => {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error("Error forwarding SSH:", err.message);
                            sshClient.end();
                            this.sshConnections.delete(dbId);
                            return reject(err);
                        }
                        sshClient.isConnected = true;
                        sshClient.stream = stream;
                        resolve(stream);
                    }
                );
            });

            // Handle tunnel disconnection or errors
            sshClient.on('error', (err) => {
                console.error(`SSH error for dbId: ${dbId}`, err.message);
                this.handleConnectionError(dbId, sshClient, reject);
            });

            sshClient.on('end', () => {
                console.log(`SSH connection ended for dbId: ${dbId}`);
                this.handleConnectionError(dbId, sshClient);
            });

            sshClient.on('close', () => {
                console.log(`SSH connection closed for dbId: ${dbId}`);
                this.handleConnectionError(dbId, sshClient);
            });

            sshClient.connect({
                ...config,
                readyTimeout: 20000,
                keepaliveInterval: 20000,
                keepaliveCountMax: 3,
                debug: true
            });
        });
    }

    handleConnectionError(dbId, sshClient, reject) {
        this.cleanupSSHClient(dbId);
        if (reject) reject(new Error(`SSH tunnel disconnected for dbId ${dbId}`));
    }

    cleanupSSHClient(dbId) {
        const sshClient = this.sshConnections.get(dbId);
        if (sshClient) {
            sshClient.end();
            this.sshConnections.delete(dbId);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Recreate the MySQL pool if it's no longer valid.
     */
    async recreatePoolIfLost(dbId, pool) {
        try {
            const connection = await pool.getConnection();
            connection.release();
            return pool; // Connection is valid, return the pool
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(`Pool for dbId ${dbId} is no longer valid. Recreating...`, err.message);
            this.pools.delete(dbId);
            return null; // Return null so that a new pool can be created
        }
    }

    async getDBPool(dbId, dbConfig, sshConfig) {
        if (this.pools.has(dbId)) {
            console.log("Reusing connection pool for dbId:", dbId);
            const existingPool = this.pools.get(dbId);

            // Check if the pool is still valid
            const validPool = await this.recreatePoolIfLost(dbId, existingPool);
            if (validPool) {
                return validPool;
            }
        }

        // Create a new SSH tunnel and connection pool
        const tunnelStream = await this.createSSHTunnel(dbId, sshConfig);
        const pool = mysql.createPool({
            ...dbConfig,
            stream: tunnelStream,
            waitForConnections: true,
            connectionLimit: 50,
            queueLimit: 0,
            enableKeepAlive: true,
            keepAliveInitialDelay:  0,
            namedPlaceholders: true,
            debug: true
        });

        this.pools.set(dbId, pool);
        return pool;
    }
}

module.exports = new PoolManager();

pool.js
const PoolManager = require('./pool_manager');

async function getDBPool(dbId, dbConfig, sshConfig) {
    if (sshConfig) {
        return PoolManager.getDBPool(dbId, dbConfig, sshConfig); // With SSH tunnel
    } else {
        return PoolManager.getDBPool(dbId, dbConfig); // Without SSH tunnel
    }
}

module.exports = { getDBPool };

Fetch Filter loop
const {getDBPool} = require('../../../config/database/pool');
...
data = await Filter.fetchAll().then(res => res.toJSON());

      if(withOptions){
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
          let db_id = data[i].db_id;

          let connection;
          if(db_id){
            const db = await Database.forge().where({id: db_id}).fetch().then(res => res.toJSON());
            const db_string = JSON.parse(`{${db.connection_string}}`);
            db_string.dateStrings = true;
      
            if(db.requiresSshTunnel){
              const ssh_string = JSON.parse(`{${db.ssh_string}}`);
              ssh_string.keyFile = db.keyFile;
              connection = await getDBPool(db.id, db_string, ssh_string);
            }
            else {
              connection = await getDBPool(db.id, db_string);
            }
          }
          
          
          let new_options = await Filter.getFilterOptions(connection, data[i], account_id);
          data[i].options = new_options;
        }
      }
...

Console Output
Reusing connection pool for dbId: 5
Add command: ClientHandshake
Pool for dbId 5 is no longer valid. Recreating... connect ETIMEDOUT
Reusing existing SSH tunnel for dbId: 5
Add command: ClientHandshake
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at PromisePool.query

I tried implementing error handling and retry logic to no avail. What am I missing?

I forgot to mention the error appears after being idle for a while. First few runs of query are successful since server restart then the error returns after a decent amount of idle time.
